Installing Nik4nix Gimp Plugin
Hi I just downloaded nik4nix-win-2018-10-16.7z off of sourceforge to use on Gimp.
Not sure if its the latest. But how do I install it in Gimp?
I'm running the latest Ubuntu off of a thumbdrive since something is wrong with my Bios.
Thanks.
